# PHP - save object key from json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Sorry for the noobie question, I am trying to save some json data on to my database. The problem is, i don't know how to get any of the "parent_names". The "parent_name" is always the same as the child "name".

price-data.json

```
[
    {
        "Flag": {
            "name": "Flag",
            "safe_price": "118.31",
            "safe_net_price": "110.60",
            "total_volume": 3148,
            "7_days": {
                "median_price": "118.31",
                "lowest_price": "100.00",
                "highest_price": "132.25",
                "volume": 94
            }
        },
        "Pole": {
            "name": "Pole",
            "safe_price": "81.21",
            "safe_net_price": "70.62",
            "total_volume": 1,
            "7_days": {
                "volume": 0
            }
        },
        "Net": {
            "name": "Net",
            "safe_price": "0.89",
            "safe_net_price": "0.84",
            "total_volume": 763,
            "7_days": {
                "median_price": "0.89",
                "lowest_price": "0.65",
                "highest_price": "1.08",
                "volume": 30
            }
        }
    }
]
```

php

```
$filename = "price-data.json";  
$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
$array = json_decode($data, true);


foreach($array as $row)  
 {  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_all_prices(parent_name, name, safe_price, safe_net_price, total_volume, median_price, lowest_price, highest_price, volume) VALUES (
      '".$row["parent_name"]."', 
      '".$row["parent_name"]["name"]."', 
      '".$row["parent_name"]["safe_price"]."', 
      '".$row["parent_name"]["safe_net_price"]."', 
      '".$row["parent_name"]["total_volume"]."', 
      '".$row["parent_name"]["7_days"]["median_price"]."',
      '".$row["parent_name"]["7_days"]["lowest_price"]."',
      '".$row["parent_name"]["7_days"]["highest_price"]."',
      '".$row["parent_name"]["7_days"]["volume"]."'
      )";       
 }  
 echo "All Prices inserted to database";
```

Comment: If parent_name and child's name is always the same, what's the problem? Just use twice the child's name. Otherwise you need to use `key()` function to retrieve key from array.

Comment: where is this in that json `parent_name : { }` - `foreach($array as $parent_name => $row)` perhaps?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know what the parent_name is going to be every time. @GrzegorzGajda

Comment: @Alex - it's the top level key no? such as `Flag`, `Pole` ... ?

Comment: `var_dump($array)` would show you exactly what you're dealing with. and if you don't know the keys of the object you get, then use `array_keys()` or the extended `foreach($arr as $key => $val)`

Comment: It is not in there at all, i was hoping flag,pole,net can be the top level key. @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: then yes it's the top level key, so do `foreach($array as $parent_name => $row)` and for the array access you just do `$row["7_days"]` because you are in the "parent_name" branch of the array from the loop.  Although you may have to use `$array[0]` because you have `[{..}]` an outer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the key from the current array level in the loop, you can do that by

```
 foreach($array as $parent_name => $row)
```

Adding a variable in before the `$row` variable think of this like array access

```
 array( 'key' => 'value' )
```

Same deal.  Now because you are in the "parent_name" level of the array you don't need to put the additional access key in there.  So for this

```
$row["parent_name"]["7_days"]["volume"]
```

You can just do

```
$row["7_days"]["volume"]
```

Because you will be working in this part of the json

```
        "name": "Net",
        "safe_price": "0.89",
        "safe_net_price": "0.84",
        "total_volume": 763,
        "7_days": {
            "median_price": "0.89",
            "lowest_price": "0.65",
            "highest_price": "1.08",
            "volume": 30
        }
```

Then because you have an outer array wrapper on your json `[{ .. }]` those square brackets. you may need to do  `$array[0]` or `$array = reset($array)`.  Reset is probably better ( if that turns out to be the case ) because you will avoid some warning messages from PHP if the array is empty.  Essentially, trying to access a key of `0` will give you an undefined index warning if it's empty..